# Non-exhaustive pattern

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I wrote a function that would take a list [a] and would group all equal values into another list - so the output would be something like [[a]]. Now I used ghci with (-W) Warnings enabled, and it seems one of my patterns isn't exhaustive - could you help me find the case my pattern doesn't match yet ?  <3

```
h :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
h [] = []
h (x:xs) = help x xs [x] []
 where help :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
       help _ [] s [] = [s]                            --line 15
       help _ [] s n = s : (h n) 
       help a (y:ys) s n | a == y = help a ys (y:s) n
                         | a /= y = help a ys s (y:n)
```

```
test.hs:15:8: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘help’: Patterns not matched: _ (_:_) _ _
   |
15 |        help _ [] s [] = [s]
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, because it's technically possible that neither of your guards `a == y` or `a /= y` are true.

Even though it's commonly assumed that `Eq` means an equivalence relation, the Haskell Report actually doesn't define any laws for it. In particular, the "custom" `x /= y = not (x == y)` can be violated. (And even if it were a law, those still aren't enforced by the compiler.) Consider this:

```
data BadIdea = BadIdea

instance Eq BadIdea where
    _ == _ = False
    _ /= _ = False
```

Although you really shouldn't do that, you *can*, and then your program would crash since neither case was true.

The easiest way for you to fix this is to replace `a /= y` with `otherwise`. This is analogous to the fact that you wouldn't write `if a == y then ...` and `if a /= y then ...` but would rather write `if a == y then ... else ...`. Since in practice, no real types have an `Eq` instance that's so pathological, this won't really change your program's behavior (and if you did use such a type, it would just consider them unequal instead of crashing).

Comment: WOW! I'm completely thunderstruck that this is the cause of the warning.
Thank you. Much love <3

Comment: @marvinm Even assuming instances are lawful, in the general case one could use very complex logical formulas as guard conditions, and GHC can not decide whether they catch all cases -- indeed the problem is undecidable, in general. When checking patterns, GHC conservatively assumes all the guards in a group might be false, unless they end with `| True = ...` or `| otherwise = ...`. Also, if you are sure that they are exhaustive, using `otherwise` in the last one is more efficient than repeating any other check.

Comment: @chi Worth mentioning that that's only true in general for Boolean guards. It's possible for some pattern guards to be considered complete on their own, for example.